# how to fill rows with help of index pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, sklearn-pandas

**how to fill rows with help of index pandas?**

I have dataframe like

```
    Alert number    Age Job Loan
0        0          58   4   0
2        2          44   9   0
4        4          35   4   0
6        6          41   0   0
8        8          29   0   0
```

I have another dataframe with same no of columns and different index values like

```
     Alert number   Age Job Loan
1        1          58   4   0
3        3          44   9   0
5        5          35   4   0
7        7          41   0   0
9        9          29   0   0
```

**How to combine the above two rows sequentially in pandas?**

Like the below dataframe

```
    Alert number    Age Job Loan
0        0          58   4   0
1        1          58   4   0
2        2          44   9   0
3        3          44   9   0
4        4          35   4   0
5        5          35   4   0
6        6          41   0   0
7        7          41   0   0
8        8          29   0   0
9        9          29   0   0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with sorting by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_values('Alert number', ignore_index=True)
```

Or by [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index()
```

Comment: My problem is i'm having two dataframes where one dataframe has around 7000 rows and another has 18000 rows. The first dataframe which contains 7000 rows are included in the 18000 rows, but the only difference is the 7000 rows are outliers. So i want to add back outliers to my main data with extra column. I'm editing my question please check

Comment: @NithinReddy - I see no EDIT, but maybe need `df2.update(df1)` ?